# Quartz.Net and dependancy injection or calling a job from external dll at runtime

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to evaluate Quartz.Net.

I tested it with adding a class which implemented IJob in the executing assembly and it worked.

Now I want to develop an Job Scheduler in which I can add jobs at runtime.

How to proceed.

Edit:

If it seems subjective I have following specific question.

How to add external class/dll which are unknown at the design time to Quartz.net based scheduler?